# Update text in page without refreshing in nodejs using content of txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fs

I am working on a node.js app where I am watching a `txt` file using `fs.watchFile` and I am able to print the changes in the file synchronously but I want it to update the content in the `GET` route page but the route is not opening.

Here's my code:

```
const fs=require('fs')
const express=require('express')
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const app=express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get("/test",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("hello")
}
)
var prev=""
app.get("/log",(req,res)=>{
    fs.watchFile("test.txt",function(current, previous) {
        console.log("File changed!");
        file = fs.readFileSync("test.txt");
        console.log("file"+String(file));
        console.log("prev"+String(prev));
        var output=getDifference(String(prev),String(file));
        prev=file
        res.json(String(output));
        
    });
})


app.listen(5000)
```

In `localhost:5000/log` route I want to listen to text file channges and show on the page without refreshing.

Thanks

Comment: I think, using RESTful API you will not be able to solve this problem. You can have a look into https://socket.io/ and implement it accordingly.

Comment: @gypsyCoder are right the possible way by using socket.io to emit custom event when the file changed this event will call javascript method in HTML taking whatever data you want to view and in this case, you will be able to change dom attributes using normal js code